# OTP Code Issue using Firebase and Android Studio

Tags: java, android

OTP Code Issue---Firebase

I am not getting text(SMS)OTP message from Fire base but if I enter the code manually then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your app sha1 in the firebase will resolve this issue.